# What is the default kernel-size, Zero-padding and stride for keras.layers.Conv2D?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, zero-padding

What are the default Kernel-Size, Zero-Padding, and Stride arguments in Conv2D (keras.layers.Conv2D)? What happens if these arguments are not specified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the documentation here: https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/

In python you can give default values for parameters of a function, If you don't specify these parameters while calling the function, defaults are used instead.

In the link above you'll find that Conv2D has the parameters:

```
filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None
```

only filters and kernel_size parameters must be given, others are optional or has default  values next to them.

Answer (score 1):

As this [link](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/) suggests, it has a structure like this:

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters,
    kernel_size,
    strides=(1, 1),
    padding="valid",
    data_format=None,
    dilation_rate=(1, 1),
    groups=1,
    activation=None,
    use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
    bias_initializer="zeros",
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    bias_regularizer=None,
    activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None,
    bias_constraint=None,
    **kwargs
    )
```

You have to specify `filters` and `kernel_size`. These parameters have no default.

Default `padding` is `valid`, which means **no zero-padding**, and the default `strides` is `(1,1)`.